# GLUT is working fine but OpenGL is not doing anything

Tags: opengl, graphics, visual-studio-2013

The exact same code snippet is working on another machine but its not working properly for me. The **GLUT is working absolutely fine** as it open the created window but the line segment is not shown on the window which means there is a **problem with opengl**. It is not even **changing the background color** of the window.

I even test the opengl on my windows with a testing application and its working fine.

```
#ifdef WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#endif
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>

void init(void){
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, 400.0, 0.0, 400.0);
}

void linesegment(void){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2i(180, 15);
    glVertex2i(10, 145);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50);
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 400);
    glutCreateWindow("Testing Open GL");

    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(linesegment);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you're running into the rather new class of problems introduced by compositing graphics systems (Aero in Windows, Quartz Extreme on MacOS X and a multitude of various programs on Linux/X11). The gist of the problem is, that compositing is inherently double buffered: There's always an offscreen (back) buffer for the window to be drawn. And when a program indicates that it's finished with drawing the compositor will integrate it into the on-screen image.

This however brings a few caveats. Most importantly, single buffered drawing somehow needs to indicate that it's finished. While OpenGL's `glFinish` call should suffice from a implementors point of view, most compositing systems are not sensitive to it. You'll have to create a double buffered window pixel format and do a buffer swap to make the compositor present your image.

So for your program:

- replace `GLUT_SINGLE` with `GLUT_DOUBLE` in `glutInitDisplayMode`
- replace `glFlush` with `glutSwapBuffers`

Comment: awesome man you saved the day. Thanks a lot.

I need to ask one more thing that what will you do in order to make to image horizontally mirror. I used the glscalef(1 , -1, 1) function on the keyboard press function on the same programe. The starts to display on every alternate key press. In my opinion it goes to some negative axis that is not on the graph. I want to show it on the screen . What can I do for it ? Thanks !

Comment: @Vyper: There are various way to do this (you should not call glScale, or any other OpenGL related function in the event handler though). In your case I presume you're using a quad to draw the texture. So I suggest you add a variable (you'll have to make it global when using GLUT) storing the flip state. And depending on the flip state you swap the texture coordinates for the quad's vertices accordingly. Another method would be using a flip state uniform passed to the fragment shader, that flips the texture coordinates internally. Apropos shaders: You should learn using them; much easier.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I am not using QUADS. I have made a square using Points with the for loop. The color shade is also handled logically within those loops. I was assuming that there must be a function in opengl which can horizontally mirror the image. Is there a function that can do so or I have to do it manually ?

Comment: @Vyper: Well, technically you could flip the texture coordinate matrix (`glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE); glLoadIdentity(); glScalef(1, -1, 1);`) which would have the effect you ask for. But that's just modifying the texture coordinates again (which is perfectly fine). Anyway, are you telling me, that you are drawing the pixel *point by point*? Do you have any idea of how inefficient that is? Also if you do that in a `glBegin … glEnd` block you're starving the GPU because the CPU is spending several orders of magnitude more time on making function calls, than the GPU doing actual work.