# How can i change my background color?

Tags: opengl

How can i change my background color?

I can't change my background color.....

i trying uninstall my vs2015... and install again again...
[image]

other my friends background color is white. it's same code.

my other laptop is good working for vs2015(same code and setting)

but my new laptop is make this problem.

please, i need help this problem

[image]

```
#include <glut.h>

void MyDisplay(){
    float vertices[3][2]={{ 0.0,0.0 },{ 250.0,500.0 },{ 500.0,0.0 }};
    float p[2] = { 75.0, 50.0 };
    int i, j;

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    for (j = 0; j<50000; j++) {
        i = rand() % 3;
        p[0] = (p[0] + vertices[i][0]) / 2.0;
        p[1] = (p[1] + vertices[i][1]) / 2.0;
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2fv(p);
        glEnd();
    } glFlush();    
}

void MyInit() {
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0); 
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, 500.0, 0.0, 500.0, 1, -1);
}

void main(int argc, char** argv) { 
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0); 
    glutCreateWindow("Sierpinski Gasket");
    glutDisplayFunc(MyDisplay);
    MyInit();
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Can you show code?

Comment: No code... really?

Comment: sorry , my first time question in stackoverflow.

Comment: Try `GLUT_DOUBLE` and `glutSwapBuffers()`.  Single-buffered rendering in composited windowing systems can be...weird.

Comment: I try that code `glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE);` and `glBegin(GL_POINTS); glVertex2fv(p); glEnd();
  
 } glutSwapBuffers();` .
this code is good working ...
but Why am I having this problem for me...?

anyway, thank you for your answer! : ) 


I need to find more answers to this question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19753811/44729

Answer (score 0):

```
void MyInit() {
  glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0); 
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glOrtho(0.0, 500.0, 0.0, 500.0, 1, -1);
}
```

You should play with the line `glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);`
Just change the values from 0 to 1.